# Xamarin.android : using listeners in C#

Tags: java, c#, xamarin.android

i have an android library written in java, and i want to translate it to Xamarin android C#, but i'm facing a problem in using listeners.

for example, in java, the method of using an OnClick listener for a button is :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Perform action on click
}
});
```

but in C#, there is no such thing as new View.IOnClickListener().

I know i should use

```
button.Click+= (o,e) => {
 // Perform action on click
};
```

but i'm not talking about this event, there are more complex listeners in Android, like GestureDetector and ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener. in Android Java, these are added the same way (anonymous class).

How are these anonymous types used in C#? including classes and interfaces? and how to use the same way that java uses, in C#?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's going to vary per situation.  In most cases, the OnClickListener will translate to a Click event, but gestures are a little more involved.  See the [help documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/gestures/create_a_gesture_listener/) for more info; there's a good example of gestures, such as this listener example taken from there:

```
public class Activity1 : Activity, GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener
{
   public bool OnDown(MotionEvent e)
   {
   }
   public bool OnFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
   {
   }
   public void OnLongPress(MotionEvent e) {}
   public bool OnScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
   {
   }
   public void OnShowPress(MotionEvent e) {}
   public bool OnSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
   {
       return false;
   }
}
```

The listener gives you more control over the user interaction.